# What is the correct way to send ArrayBuffer or Blob across and reconstruct them?

Tags: node.js, angular, express, blob, angular-httpclient

I've read through a dozen posts on how to convert between `ArrayBuffer` to `Blob` or to `Uint8Array` etc. before sending the data to the client side... but I can't seem to be able to get it to work at all. When I do get the data through, I was not able to reconstruct them back as a `Blob` before outputting it to a file..

```
const Blob = require('cross-blob');
const randomBytes = require('randombytes');

const buffer = randomBytes(1024); // Supposed to give me Buffer
```

The followings were the stuff I tried...

```
data = buffer;
```

^ gives me `<Buffer 11 22 33 ...>`

```
data = Uint8Array.from(buffer);
```

^ gives me an array of integer, this looked the most promising? but when arrived to the client side, it became an object with indexes and byte value...

```
data = Uint8Array.from(buffer).buffer;
```

^ gives `ArrayBuffer { byteLength: 1024}`, when inspect it shows `size: 2` and `type: 'text/plain'`...

```
data = new Blob(buffer, { type: 'application/octet-stream' });
data = new Blob([new Uint8Array(buffer, buffer.byteOffset, buffer.length)], { type: 'application/octet-stream' });
data = new Blob([Uint8Array.from(buffer)], { type: 'application/octet-stream' });
```

^ all these, when arrived to the client side also with `size: 2` and `type: 'text/plain'`...

On the server side, I am running Express:

```
router.get('/test/*', function(req, res, next) {
  ...
  let data = myFunctionThatGeneratesData();
  res.send(data);
});
```

On the client side, I'm requesting it like this (Angular/TypeScript):

```
this.http.get('/test/random-bytes-array', {
  responseType: 'blob'  // also tried 'arraybuffer'
}).subscribe(data => {
  debugger;
  console.log(data);
});
```

I must be doing something wrong... I am trying to send multiple chunk of binary data over, either as an `ArrayBuffer`, `Uint8Array` or `Blob` (whatever works) and when arriving at the other end, combine them back into a `Blob`.

Comment: In the [Express doc](https://expressjs.com/en/4x/api.html#res.send), it pretty clearly states: "The body parameter [for res.send()] can be a Buffer object, a String, an object, Boolean, or an Array."  If you send a Buffer object, then it will set the Content-Type to “application/octet-stream” unless you set the content-type yourself to something else that is appropriate for the data in the buffer.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In Node.js, [`crypto.randomBytes`](https://nodejs.org/api/crypto.html#crypto_crypto_randombytes_size_callback) returns a [`Buffer`](https://nodejs.org/api/buffer.html#buffer_buffer). This is the correct type to use for sending raw data to the client.

When using Express, it is important to set the correct content-type of the response using [`res.type()`](https://expressjs.com/en/4x/api.html#res.type). However, when sending a `Buffer`, if the content-type header is not set in any other middleware, then [express will use `application/octet-stream` by default](https://expressjs.com/en/4x/api.html#res.send).

> When the parameter is a Buffer object, the method sets the Content-Type response header field to "application/octet-stream", unless previously defined.

```js
router.get('/test/*', function(req, res, next) {
  ...
  let data = myFunctionThatGeneratesData();
  res.type('application/octet-stream').send(data);
  // ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^ might not be necessary
});
```

And lastly in Angular, using the `responseType: 'blob'` is correct:

```js
this.http.get('/test/random-bytes-array', {
  responseType: 'blob'
}).subscribe(data => {
  console.log(data);
});
```

Comment: Oh my god... FML... So I went back and try the simplest thing `data = buffer;` and is working now. Originally I did not use the `responseType: 'blob'`, then I tried many other ways (as shown in my post) to send the binary over with `responseType: 'blob'` but i never went back to try the simplest `data = buffer;`!!!!!!